# SQLAlchemy Large Number Truncation/Rounding Issue in Oracle

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I manage a number of ETL jobs and among them I have connections to APIs like Facebook graph and Google Doubleclick, which use large numeric unique identifiers. We use an Oracle database to stage some of this data and combine it with our own data. The problem I keep running in to is that when I go to insert these large numeric IDs into a number column via SQLAlchemy (which uses cx_Oracle) significant digits get truncated.

Example:
 1234567890726531 becomes 1234567890726530

Workaround:
To get around this, I've been using VARCHAR2 data types to hold the text representation of the IDs, since that retains all of the significant digits.

I believe it is related to these bug threads:

- [regression in numeric precision behavior in 6.0 #68](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/68)
- [v6.0.2 Issue 68 Redux? #98](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/98)

(I was unable to replicate the cursor code mentioned in these threads to test that solution in my situation)

Some sample code (or the relevant parts extracted from it) for the Facebook example is as follows:

```
[...code that populate the "buffer" list]
schema,table_name = 'some_schema','some_table'
engine = create_engine(enginestr)
metadata = MetaData()
table  = Table(table_name,
                 metadata,
                 schema=schema,
                 autoload=True,
                 autoload_with=self.engine)
buf=[]
for i in buffer:
    d={
        'id':i[1]['id'],
        'id_char':i[1]['id'],
        'name':i[1]['name'],
        'status':i[1]['status'],
        'page_id':i[0]['id']
    }
    buf+=[d]
engine.execute(table.insert(),buf)
```

A buffer entry looks like this:

```
[(<Page> {
      "id": "FacebookPageName"
  }, <LeadgenForm> {
      "id": "123456789012345",
      "leadgen_export_csv_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=123456789012345&type=form&source_type=graph_api",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "name": "Leadgen Form Name",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
  })]
```

The table is essentially this:

```
create table some_schema.some_table (
id number primary key,
name varchar2(512 char),
status varchar2(30 char),
updated timestamp with time zone default systimestamp,
id_char varchar2(64 char)
);
```

After running the code above, the result of this SQL should be nothing

```
select to_char(t.id) ,t.id_char from some_schema.some_table t where t.id<>t.id_Char;
```

however, it does return results (slightly altered to preserve privacy)

```
NUMERIC_ID  ID_CHAR
1234567890726530    1234567890726531
1234567890585300    1234567890585296
1234567890103880    1234567890103882
1234567890185790    1234567890185794
1234567890359660    1234567890359664
1234567890793130    1234567890793131
1234567890250270    1234567890250272
1234567890467220    1234567890467223
1234567890905240    1234567890905241
1234567890369260    1234567890369255
```

This DML updates it to show as expected as shows me the the problem lies on the python side:

```
update some_schema.some_table t set t.id = t.id_char where t.id<>t.id_Char;
```

Is there a better way to handle:

- Table reflection
- Data type conversion
- Inserting
- Anything

Such that my large numeric values do not get truncated? Right now using the string-type containers for the IDs seems to be working, but isn't the best in terms of storage space per row, which becomes a concern with larger datasets.

Supplemental Information:

- Python Version: 3.6.2
- SQLAlchemy Version: 1.2.0
- cx-Oracle Version: 6.1

Edit:

At the suggestion of Anthony Tuininga, I tried directly inserting the records via cx-Oracle and it did not cause the rounding issue above. This leads me to conclude that my issue lies either in my implementation of SQLAlchemy or the SQLAlchemy library itself.

```
buf=[]
columns = ('id','id_char','name','status','page_id')
for i in buffer:
    d=(
        i[1]['id'],
        i[1]['id'],
        i[1]['name'],
        i[1]['status'],
        i[0]['id']
    )
    buf+=[d]

from ouplax.database import KEY
import cx_Oracle
config = {
    'server'     : 'TNSName',
    'username'   : 'username',
    'schema'     : 'some_schema',
    'table_name' : 'some_table',
    'columns'    : ','.join(columns),
    'binds'      : ','.join( [':{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,len(columns)+1)] )
}
k = KEY(server=config['server'],username=config['username'],keyHeader='PYSQL') #Object for storing/retrieving credentials
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(config['username'],k.getpass(),server)
cursor = cx_Oracle.Cursor(connection)
stmt = 'truncate table {schema}.{table_name}'.format(**config)
print(stmt)
cursor.execute(stmt)
stmt = 'insert into {schema}.{table_name} ({columns}) values ({binds})'.format(**config)
print(stmt)
cursor.prepare(stmt)
cursor.executemany(None, buf)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Can you add information on platform you are using? Python version you are using? cx_Oracle version you are using? sqlalchemy version you are using? Have you tried using cx_Oracle directly (without sqlalchemy) to see if this is specific to sqlalchemy?

Comment: cx_Oracle should have no difficulty transforming integers of any size that Oracle supports into Oracle without truncation. Using floating point numbers is a different matter, of course. There you are limited to 53 significant binary digits.

Comment: Added version information. I have been using SQLAlchemy to abstract the interaction with cx_Oracle, so I have not tried the inserts directly with cx_Oracle; that's a good idea. I'll see if I can narrow the issue down that way

Comment: So it's not an issue on your side from what I can tell, @AnthonyTuininga. Code posted above

Comment: It would seem that way. I'd log an issue with the sqlalchemy project. If its a combined issue Mike Bayer will be certain to contact me! :-)

Comment: @Sethionic did you ever log an issue with Sqlalchemy? If so, can you share the link?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem myself and filed a bug report in SQLAlchemy repo [(link)](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4309/query-with-a-big-number-returns-wrong). The issue was resolved in the [SQLAlchemy 1.2.11 release](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/changelog_12.html#change-f782b08ad88a2102096dbcacc8cd9974):

> **[oracle] [bug]** For cx_Oracle, Integer datatypes will now be bound to “int”, per advice from the cx_Oracle developers. Previously, using cx_Oracle.NUMBER caused a loss in precision within the cx_Oracle 6.x series.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov I wanted to comment, but couldn't because of insufficient reputation. Thought I'd rather post an answer than nothing at all then.

Comment: @Emilijus oh ye... I have no idea why it requires X points to be able to comment that's pretty strange to me xaxa